# How do I plot the dataframe with only 2 columns(text and int)?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, k-means

```
   index            reviews              label
0    0  i admit the great majority of...    1
1    1  take a low budget inexperienced ... 0
2    2  everybody has seen back to th...    1
3    3  doris day was an icon of b...       0
4    4  after a series of silly fun ...     0
```

I've a dataframe of movie reviews and I've predicted label column(1-postive , 0-negative review) using kmeans.labels_ . How do I visualise /plot the above?

Desired output: scatter plot of 1's and 0's

Code tried :

```
colors = ['red', 'blue']
pred_colors = [colors[label] for label in km.labels_]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.scatter(x='index',y='label',c=pred_colors)
```

Output: Plot with a red dot at center

Comment: Hi, you need to provide a sample desired output figure. Currently your question is more open and broad. There are several ways of visualizing but you need to know for yourself first, how the desired output should look like

Comment: Desired output would be a scatter plot of 1's and 0's. @Bazingaa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This plot comes from:
http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/Python4_DataAnalysis.html

You do not have values to plot on the x-axis, so we can simply use the index.
The reviews could be added to data as another column.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
data = [1,0,1,0,0]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=range(5), columns=['label'])
#
# line plot
#df.reset_index().plot(x='index', y='label') # turn index into column for plotting on x-axis
#
# scatter plot
ax1 = df.reset_index().plot.scatter(x='index', y='label', c='DarkBlue')
#
plt.tight_layout() # helps prevent labels from being cropped
plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried the given solution (mentioned in edited ques) and got a single dot .I need to get 2 clusters one with red dots and one with blue

Comment: The code you tried seems like you are on the right track. Using the index on the x-axis is not going to give you "clusters" of dots.  You should think about what is the proper x-axis variable. Maybe the movie reviewer, or type of movie, the movie studio, etc., Also, please give us a small data set to work as an example.

Comment: Okay , I've provided a small dataset in the edited question

Comment: Excellent, I added a plot from a website just as an example of clustering. The plot is for plant characteristics (sepal length versus sepal width). Sepal length and sepal width have some variation in them and you can see clustering based on the type of plant. Your example simply has 0 and 1 for the review. To see clustering of data you will have to pick at least two things that vary.